# What does this mdx mean

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I know the end result of this MDX, basically it will SUM the `Amount measure` across all previous Periods in the `Calendar Hierarchy` inclusive of the current period.

```
SUM({null:[Date].[Calendar Hierarchy].CurrentMember},[Measures].[Amount])
```

What I would like to know is how this works, can you please explain what the MDX is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're asking about the syntax of the MDX, or how this is processed in the cube, but let me answer the MDX question.

So, you have a calculation defined which is going to SUM a measure across a set of members.

```
SUM(
    {null : [Date].[Calendar Hierarchy].CurrentMember},
    [Measures].[Amount]
)
```

The `:` is a Range operator. It defines a set, in the natural order of the hierarchy, between a start and end member: `start : end`. If start is null, then the set starts from the first member of the level the end member is on.
See the docs here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146001.aspx

Presumably this is being used in a query where you are selecting the `[Date]` on one axis, and want to see the running total:

```
WITH MEMBER total AS 
    SUM({null:[Date].[Calendar Hierarchy].CurrentMember},[Measures].[Amount])
SELECT
    total ON COLUMNS,
    [Date].[Calendar Hierarchy].Members ON ROWS
FROM [Your Cube]
```

The calculation is evaluated for each row (member in `[Date].[Calendar Hierarchy]`) and for each one, the set defined by `{null : [Date].[Calendar Hierarchy].CurrentMember}` is all the members up to and including the current one.